# How to pass value from datepicker to database?

Tags: php, mysql, jquery-ui

by using form and post method in my program. It seems like my values of calendar are not able to insert into my database. I'm using jquery's datepicker and php to code. Please advice. Thanks

Comment: Give us some relevant code. **Not everything** but **several lines** where you retrieve data from the post and try to put into the database.

Comment: what's the format of date generated by jquery?

Answer (score 0):

chances are your database is structured with a date format or datetime format.  This is fine, but you will have to change the format of the date in the jquery UI after it is posted.  Therefore if you have it as 12/19/2010 it would have to be changed to 2010-12-19 for the database to accept it.  This is just a random guess since I don't know much more from your question.